# Change of variable leads to contradiction for a simple integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

Let $$I = \int_{a}^{b}(x - k)^2 dx$$ then

$$I = \int_{a}^{b}(x^2 - 2xk + k^2) dx = \left[\frac{x^3}{3} - x^2k + xk^2\right]_a^b$$

but also if we let $u = x - k \Rightarrow du = dx$ with $x = a \Rightarrow u = a - k, x = b \Rightarrow u = b - k$ then

$$I = \int_{a - k}^{b - k} u^2 du = \left[\frac{u^3}{3}\right]_{a - k}^{b - k} = \left[\frac{(x - k)^3}{3}\right]_{a}^{b} = \left[\frac{x^3}{3} - x^2k + xk^2 - \frac{k^3}{3}\right]_a^b$$

Which obviously can't be true unless $k = 0$. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Alternatively, just write:$$\int_a^b (x-k)^2dx=\frac{(x-k)^3}{3}\bigg|_a^b=\frac{(b-k)^3-(a-k)^3}{3}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$k$ is a constant with no terms of $x$ associated with it. So on substituting the limits,

$-\frac{k^3}{3}$ will get cancelled by $\frac{k^3}{3}$.

Comment: Oh makes sense! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: +1 Years ago, there was this commercial for an small electric air freshener that would heat the fragrance to evaporate it, and you'd use it by inserting it into an electrical outlet.  And they had a jingle/slogan that TO THIS DAY remains stuck in my head... "Plug it in, plug it in."  And the damn song keeps replaying in my mind every time I see a math problem in which the solution becomes evident on substitution.  I don't know why I feel compelled to share that story.

Comment: @heropup True! 